# Website is loading twice unnecessarily

Tags: performance

In [pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/) my dev website is loading twice. I tried googling and added and searched every option it has to offer like the following. But it's not working. I have also uninstalled some of the themes but still no success.
Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Site Url: [my site](http://109.74.4.178/lotustravel/)

[Website Loads Twice Unnecessarily](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165803/website-loads-twice-unnecessarily)

Comment: To offer any help with this, we need the URL of the website.

Comment: @Emil added the url ...

Comment: Strange, I can't really see what's wrong, but at least it doesn't happen from the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the result from Pingdom (https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/TlPTR/http://109.74.4.178/lotustravel/) it looks like the redirects are all from your advertising providers. So you don't have much choice in how they work and there redirects.